# find dictionary with min value in a list of dictionaries for a given key

Tags: python, dictionary, maps

I'm new to python and trying to find a solution to the problem:

The problem is to write a function that scans the array of records and returns the record that has the minimum value for a specified key. Records that do not contain the specified key are considered to have value `0` for the key.

Note that keys may map to negative values!

My solution:

```
def min_by_key(k,ld):
    min_val=min([d.get(k,0) for d in ld])
    for dt in ld:
        if dt.get(k,0)==min_val:            
            return dt


assert min_by_key("a", [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 2}]) == {"a": 1, "b": 2} 
assert min_by_key("a", [{"a": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": 2}])  == {"a": 1, "b": 2} 
assert min_by_key("b", [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 2}]) == {"a": 2} 
assert min_by_key("a", [{}]) == {} 
assert min_by_key("b", [{"a": -1}, {"b": -1}]) == {"b": -1}
```

It is working but need to know is there any better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `min` with key that compares key value `k`

```
>>> def min_by_key(k,ld):
...     return min(ld, key=lambda d: d.get(k, 0))
... 
>>>
```

All your asserts pass

```
>>> assert min_by_key("a", [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 2}]) == {"a": 1, "b": 2} 
>>> assert min_by_key("a", [{"a": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": 2}])  == {"a": 1, "b": 2} 
>>> assert min_by_key("b", [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 2}]) == {"a": 2} 
>>> assert min_by_key("a", [{}]) == {} 
>>> assert min_by_key("b", [{"a": -1}, {"b": -1}]) == {"b": -1} 
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is as simple as this:

```
def min_by_key(key, dicts):
    return min(dicts, key=lambda d: d.get(key, 0))
```

In this way you can sort by `key`, and in case there is no such value in a dict `0` is used.