# how to get the smallest value of a key in multiple dictionaries nested in a list?

Tags: python

I have something like this

```
data = [{'name': 'abc', 'id': 'abc123','price': '$10'},
       {'name': 'def', 'id': 'efg123','price': '$15'},
       {'name': 'ghi', 'id': 'ghi123','price': '$5'}, ]
```

what I want to do is first strip the '$' sign from the value of 'price' key from all the dictionaries and then compare the values in all the dictionaries and print the smallest one in them.

I did this for removing the symbol

```
for i in data:
    data_price = i['price']
    new_price = data_price.strip('$')
    print(new_price)
```

But I don't know how I compare all the values and then get the smallest one, and I also then need to know in which dictionary that smallest value belongs to because I also need its id.

how do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187292

Answer (score 2):

you can get it as this

```
min_data = min(data, key=lambda dic: float(dic['price'].lstrip('$')))
```

same approach with `for` loop in simple way

```
>>> def get_min(arr):
        store_min = {}
        for record in arr:
                val = float(record['price'].lstrip('$'))
                if val not in store_min:
                        store_min[val] = []
                store_min[val].append(record)
        minimum_prices = store_min.keys()
        min_price = min(minimum_prices)
        return store_min[min_price][0] 
print(get_min(data))
# output -> {'name': 'ghi', 'id': 'ghi123', 'price': '$5'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) with a key function:

```
data = [{'name': 'abc', 'id': 'abc123','price': '$10'},
        {'name': 'def', 'id': 'efg123','price': '$15'},
        {'name': 'ghi', 'id': 'ghi123','price': '$5'}, ]


m = min(data, key=lambda d: int(d["price"][1:]))
# {'name': 'ghi', 'id': 'ghi123', 'price': '$5'}
```

Note that you have to cast `price`
to a numerical type, so that you won't compare lexicographically (where e.g. `"10" < "5"`)